# Why git reset files to previous versions?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-reset

You see, I have a problem with git in my computer. I typed clone command in my console, but three files are modified right there to previous versions. so... when I open the IDE, the three files has modified tags.  I tried clone command many times but the problem stay there.

I'm using

git 2.15.1 (Apple Git-101)

Webstorm IDE 2018.2

Steps done

`cd go/to/path`

`git clone url-repo`

so... i type `git status` and console show anything like

```
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working
directory)

modified:   src/app/http/controllers/Controller.js
modified:   src/app/models/PermissionModel.js
modified:   src/app/models/RoleModel.js
```

I'm not understanding, If the project has recently been cloned.

Sorry for my English.  :3  thanks for you answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you are using clone in an appropriate way here.  Can you edit your question and let us know exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: if you want to reset to original in the branch you need to make a `git rebase -i master`